# vue 2.0 Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-elixir

I am using a Laravel Vue setup and pulling in Laravel Elixir, Webpack and [laravel-elixir-vue-2](https://github.com/vuejs/laravel-elixir-vue-2)  package.

I have looked at several other SO questions and I know this is usually a problem with not referencing the standalone version of vue.js

However, the laravel-elixir-vue-2 package aliases vue to the standalone version so templates can be loaded from .vue files. Still, I get this error every time:

```
[Vue:Warn] vue 2.0 Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. (found in component <top> at ../resources/assets/js/components/top.vue)
```

I can see that vue.js is being pulled in from vue/dist/vue.js?0598:2611  in the console.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import top from './components/top.vue'

new Vue({
el: '#app',
components: { top }
})

//I've also tried this: 

// new Vue({
//  components: {
//    top
//  },
// render: h => h(top),
// }).$mount('#app')
```

top.vue

```
<template>
   <div class="top">
     <p>hi</p>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
 export default {};
</script>
```

index.blade.php

```
<div>
   <div id="app">
<top></top>
   </div>
</div>
{!! HTML::script('js/app.js') !!}
```

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "prod": "gulp --production",
  "dev": "gulp watch"
},
"devDependencies": {
   "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.0",
   "gulp": "^3.9.1",
   "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
  "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
  "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2"
  }
 }
```

gulp.js

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
elixir.config.sourcemaps = true;
require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

elixir(function(mix) {
  mix.webpack('app.js', 'public/assets/js');
});
```

**Edit: update**

Changing the gulp.js syntax fixed my error.

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir')
require('laravel-elixir-vue-2')

elixir(mix => {

  mix.webpack('app.js');

  mix.styles([
    "normalize.css",
    "main.css"
    ]);

});
```

**edit:**  I added export default {}; to the template script

Comment: You haven't shown us the `top` component.

Comment: It is there as the 2nd code snippet:  top.vue

Comment: Try registering the component with `Vue.Component(name, url)` before you use it. I don't really see why you should get that error.

Comment: I have the same issue. The correct vue gets loaded. With the fresh laravel installation it worked. After I started gulp the first time, it stopped working.

Comment: @MarkusSchober  I've just got this working (well, a very basic setup working).  changing the syntax in my gulp.js file was the answer. I'll update my question to show the new syntax

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like my comment in the question, I had the same problem.
In my case I had two elixir calls like this:

```
elixir(mix => {
    mix.browserSync({
        proxy: 'example.dev',
        open: false
    });
});

elixir(mix => {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
    mix.webpack('app.js');
});
```

I don't know why, but the two elixir calls are breaking webpack.
I change my gulpfile to:

```
elixir(mix => {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
    mix.webpack('app.js');
    mix.browserSync({
        proxy: 'example.dev',
        open: false
    });
});
```

@retrograde, thx for your hint in your comment :)

Edit:
See this [Laravel Elixir Issue](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/668)

Comment: Thanks for putting it in answer form.  Hope this saves somebody hours of frustration.

Comment: Having this problem and this fixed it, bizarre problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hi have had this issue before when playing around with VueJs 2.0 RC I think what I did was create a webpack.config.js in the project root and add the following:

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js',
        }
    }
};
```

Also not sure it would make a difference but before trying the above maybe add  "vue": "^2.0.1", to your package.json file and do npm install (or just npm install vue)

Comment: The npm package 'laravel-elixir-vue-2'  includes that alias reference.  And my vue file is vue/dist/vue.js  (checked in console). Unfortunately, I still have not been able to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your component has no options, its `script` tag still has to export an empty object, so that `vue-loader` can inject the `render` function into it:

```html
<template>
   <div class="top">
     <p>hi</p>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {};
</script>
```